# Put the value of listener to a query builder (using Laravel + livewire + datatables)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, listener, laravel-livewire

This is my firstime a ask for something in StackOverflow.
I'm using datatables from https://github.com/MedicOneSystems/livewire-datatables with a Laravel and livewire project.
I wanna put the return value from a listener to a query builder to filter the result by dates (Date From and Date To)

My listener from my livewire coponents (DateFilter.php) :

```
$this->emit('dateFromChange', $this->dateFrom);
    $this->emit ('dateToChange', $this->dateTo);
```

How i get it from my datatable component (MetiersDataTable.php) regardless of the documentation of [Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events) :

```
protected $listeners = ['dateFromChange','dateToChange'];

public function dateFromChange($date){
  $dateFrom = $date;
  return $dateFrom;
}

public function dateToChange($date){
  $dateTo = $date;
  return $dateTo;
}
```

This is my function (MetiersDataTable.php) where my query is returned but the function doesn't support arguments ...

```
public function builder()
{
    return Metier::query()
    ->leftJoin("leads", "leads.metier_id", "metiers.id")
    ->whereNotIn('leads.etape_id',[6])
    ->groupBy('metiers.nom');
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If you want filters. You need to add ```filterable``` method to those columns inside ```columns``` method

Comment: Here is the code https://github.com/MedicOneSystems/demo-livewire-datatables/blob/88dcd204eded0bceacb5397a00907459bda4f349/app/Http/Livewire/ActionsDemoTable.php#L24

Comment: And demo https://livewire-datatables.com/actions